# Need to run dhclient for connecting to internet

Tags: internet, dhclient

I need to run these commands :

```
sudo dhclient  -r  #refreshed ip
sudo dhclient  # restarted ip
```

when i restart my LMDE 3 Cindy every time for connecting to internet.

So i asked here why this must be run for internet connection each time?

Thanks

Comment: Is this on a VM?

Comment: Do you have network manager installed on your OS?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager

Comment: no it is not VM